# DELETE request on a link in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, http, routes, request

I am trying to hit a route I made to make a delete HTTP request in laravel view when user clicks on 'Delete' button, but it won't work. I've read it should be done with forms in laravel.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="/admin/pages/delete/{{ $section->id }}" method="post">
    {{ method_field('delete') }}
    <button class="btn btn-sm" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

What is a proper way to handle this?
It shows me an error in the console, Bootbox: 'please specify a message' whenever I click on the button.

Route definition inside admin group:

```
    Route::delete('/pages/delete/{id}', 'PagesController@delete')->name('pages.delete');
```

Comment: What does "won't work" look like? What error do you get? What does your route definition for `/admin/pages/delete/{{ $section->id }}` look like?

Comment: We need more information, this isn't much to go off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing the csrf token in the form.
You can add

> {{ csrf_field() }}

just after your form starts.

Visit [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf) for knowing more about csrf

Answer (score 1):

You must add the the CSRF Field because all form submission must past through the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware before the request be procede by the controller

```
{{ csrf_field() }} // add this before or after the {{ method_field() }}
```